# Cordova double forward slash opening file:// rather than http://

Tags: cordova, google-dfp

I'm using a Google DFP template that is using an image from 
background-image:url(//s0.2mdn.net/ads/richmedia/studio/21515482/23079102_1358876393903_closebutton.png);

When I run the application in node, it thinks the file is in http://s0.2mdn.net/ads/richmedia/studio/21515482/23079102_1358876393903_closebutton.png

However, running it in the mobile app has it being served as file://s0.2mdn.net/ads/richmedia/studio/21515482/23079102_1358876393903_closebutton.png which obviously does not exist

Does anyone know how we can resolve this? I can't change the url because it's injected via Google's JS

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with google places autocomplete (together with the powered by google) logo.

I've fixed it inside of my CSS file (you need to overwrite). I think that's also the way you could get your problem solved. All urls were double-slashes before (//), I've manually changed them to https://

```
.pac-container::after {
  background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2.png);
}

.hdpi.pac-container::after {
  background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2_hdpi.png)
}

.pac-icon {
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png) !important;
}

.hdpi .pac-icon {
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons_hdpi.png) !important;
}
```